# C# archiving using 7zip, keeps hanging on wildcard call

Tags: c#, .net, process, zip, 7zip

Hey all quick question for you. I am trying to archive a directory of files into a zip folder using 7zip as a system process but I am running into an odd error. Whenever I do a wildcard specification in my source file name such as "*.txt" it works fine. However, once I use the wildcard * around the actual file name (Which I need to and can't work around that), 7zip just seems to hang. I can see the archive directory get created in the folder but I can't open it and I have to close 7zip down via task manager.

Any advice?

Code is below:

```
public static void archiveFiles(string executionDirectory,string workDirectory,
string[] files)

    {
       string sourceName = @"C:\mypath\*testfile*";  <----// This seems to be my issue

       string targetName = @"C:\\testcompress\archive.zip";

       ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();

       p.FileName = @"C:\program files\7-zip\7z.exe";

       p.Arguments = "a -t7z \"" + targetName + "\" \"" + sourceName + "\" -mx=9";

       p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

       Process x = Process.Start(p);

       x.WaitForExit();


    }
```

Comment: On the following page the filename is referring to 7za.exe and not 7z.exe. That might make a difference. http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip

Comment: also: Windows can cause problems here if you are not an administrator on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely getting this issue because your path @"C:\mypath*testfile*" is a verbatim string, thus using the "*" character, or other such wildcards, are being taken as literal in the path instead of wildcards. Trying taking the @ off the beginning of strings containing wildcards and that should fix your problem. You can find a more thorough explanation of what the "@" character, used in context of a prefix to strings, does here:
[Verbatim Strings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx)

Comment: I know this was a while ago but thank you, that was the majority of my issue. The other issue was for some reason the wildcard characters that were listed in some documentation online were incorrect. *___* was not the proper way to find something containing testfile.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having issues with your \'s as well as the fact that you should be using 7za.exe and not 7z.exe.   Make sure your application has access to write to the directory in question.

```
string sourceName = @"C:\mypath\*testfile*";  
string targetName = @"C:\testcompress\archive.zip"; 
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo();
p.FileName = @"C:\program files\7-zip\7za.exe"; 
p.Arguments  =  string.Format ( "a -t7z {0} {1} -mx=9",targetName,sourceName);
p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process x = Process.Start(p);
x.WaitForExit();

console.writeline(string.format("7zip returned with exit code {0}",x.ExitCode));
```

7zip exit codes can be found [here](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/exit_codes.htm)

Remember you can test it in a command prompt window to be sure that it works.

C:\program files\7-zip\7za.exe  a -t7z  C:\program files\7-zip\7za.exe C:\mypath*testfile* -mx=9